# Do I have to unload scene before loading a new one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm thinking that if I load a new scene what happens to the old one? Is it necessary to unload the old scene?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html
load scene have two mode , you can choice unload scene or not , but carefull your memroy if you dont unload old scene

Answer (score 1):

No, you can just load the new scene without unloading and it will be fine.

Plus, they marked [unloading scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadScene.html) as obselete.

> What happens to the old one.

Based on the API documentation, if you set your [loadscenemode to single](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Single.html), it will just close all the currently loaded scenes.

[LoadSceneMode.Additive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html) loads the new scene on top of the current scene.